# How to find the name of computing node in a Slurm cluster?

Tags: centos, slurm

In a computer cluster, I have the IP address of one of the computing nodes. This computing node has a name in Slurm configuration. How can I find the name that Slurm uses for this computing node?

Comment: type `getent hosts`

Answer (score 2):

The node names in `slurm.conf` must correspond to their hostname, as returned by the `hostname -s` command, and Slurm expects that those names resolve to the correct IPs.

So you should be able to run

```
getent hosts <IP>
```

to get something like

```
$ getent hosts 10.1.1.1
10.1.1.1       node001.cluster
```

In the above example, the node name as known by Slurm would be `node001`, which you can confirm with `scontrol show node node001`.